# Text search with weights for individual keywords

Tags: postgresql, solr, full-text-search, sphinx

I have a phrase to be matched against a text column. My phrase has multiple keywords, each associated with a given weight. For example,

```
Johnson [10] Software [5] Company [2]
```

I am using PostgreSQL full text search, and may use Thinking-Sphinx or Solr. Is there a function in these 3 options that allows me to search with different weights for each keyword?

Answer (score 1):

Solr allows you to do this.

Your query would look like this

```
q=(Johnson)^10 (Software)^5 (Company)^2
```

Note that the default operator (AND or OR) defined in your `schema.xml` comes into play here.

Answer (score 1):

Sphinx (and therefore Thinking-Sphinx) doesn't have a comparable feature.

But it can be emulated by various means, but to be clear, it can be tricky to setup. If this is the only reason to pick a product don't pick sphinx. But if you have other reasons to pick sphinx, then it could work out for you.

Answer (score 0):

I think perhaps you might be trying to assign weight at the wrong point, hence the question?

Your question implies that you can (somehow) assign weight at a query level (which is impossible with Sphinx).  I'm not familiar with Solr, but what happens in Solr when a query is "Software Company Johnson", and more importantly, how can you dynamically decide which is a name, which is a category and which is a type of category?  Seems much more complicated to me.

Sphinx, which I can speak for, is very good at assigning a weight to various columns on a database, especially with Rails using ThinkingSphinx.  More than likely you should have a name, category and type field with this scenario, if not I would suggest you have one.  Then you could easily rank weight to name, type and category respectively.  This should also be simple to accomplish in Solr.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it's more easy to do it during indexation.

Indeed,  you know  words in your document, you can compute a "factor" during indexation

and  so  you can use rank_expr to influence ranking  by this factor.